# What is the correct use of ie as in 'that is' and how is it written, capitals or small and with a colon?

Tags: articles

What is the correct use of ie as in 'that is' and how is it written, capitals or small and with or without a colon or semi colon?
Thanks

Comment: Have you researched this at all??

Comment: Related question, [usage of i.e in a sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107326/usage-of-i-e-in-a-sentence).

Comment: Hi, David. Welcome to EL&U. Please read the link above and you will find the answer. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: [Trask, at Sussex University](https://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/capsandabbr/abbr), is uncompromising: 'The rule about using these Latin abbreviations is very simple: don't use them.' (To be fair, he does bend a little later.)

Answer (score 1):

"i. e.," is an abbreviation of the Latin *id est*, "that is"; i. e., it follows a semi-colon, should be written in lower case letters followed by periods and a comma. As with other abbreviations, I prefer to put a space between them as well (i. e., putting a space after the period following "i."), but some people do not; others even do without the periods, although both of the latter simply look a bit "lazy" to me. However, suit yourself.

Comment: It actually translates to "it is."

Comment: @JordanPaldino but I suppose the more accurate interpretation, rather than literal translation, is "that is".