# How do you make the following look nicer: "text...,etc.)."

Tags: punctuation

Consider the following sentence

> There are many different fruits (some are harmful: apple,
>   mango, etc.).

How do you deal with `etc.).`? It doesn't look nice at all.

Comment: Personally, I just omit the `.` after `etc.` and keep the sentence-ending period. I've even stopped using the dots in `i.e.` and `e.g.`. I consider these words in their own right, now, not initialisms for some other language no one speaks anymore.

Comment: If you use *such as*, you're marking the list as descriptive, not necessarily complete. So you don't need *etc* at all.

Comment: Yea, I used "such as". But I guess the question conveys the issue.

Comment: Answered at [When "etc." is at the end of a phrase, do you place a period after it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/when-etc-is-at-the-end-of-a-phrase-do-you-place-a-period-after-it) and [usage of ie in a sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107326/usage-of-i-e-in-a-sentence/107344#107344).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This isn't a duplicate. This question asks a solution for the situation where you have "etc.)." or "etc.) text".

Comment: It's answered there. One solution is never to use abbreviation-specific  periods after _ie_, _etc_,  etc. Another is to avoid using _ie_, _etc._,  etc. The 'double punctuation is over-ugly' rule-of-thumb easily extends to your example. There's no answer that will fit in with everybody's persuasions. In fact, some hold that there are binding rules rather than guidelines. But they don't always agree on what they are, and they can conflict.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different fruits, of which some are harmful (e.g. apple and mango).

It's a little stilted, but I think it's better than the original.

Comment: Your sentence is better but the issue is how to deal with `,etc.).`. I just gave a bad example.