# One or two full points after "cc" meaning "centuries"?

Tags: punctuation, periods, end-punctuation

Would you put one or two full points after "cc" (referring to "centruries") when "cc" is the last word of a sentence? For instance:

> This event had a great impact on the country in the 15-16 cc.. At that time, religious wars tore Europe apart.
>
> Venice was an important centre of trade in the 13-16 cc.. Merchants from all over the world came to the city to sell their goods.

Comment: IMO 'cc' isn't used as an abbreviation for 'centuries'. It's just 'C'. Typically, in the 13th to 16th C without a period (unless it's the end of the sentence).

Comment: If you wish to abbreviate *centuries* to *cc.* (perhaps that's how it's generally done in your domain?) then you do not need to double up on the point if it occurs at the end of a sentence.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Punctuation around abbreviations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/711/punctuation-around-abbreviations) But see also [Usage of ie in a sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107326/usage-of-i-e-in-a-sentence/107344#107344) for the periodless variant/s Weather Vane shows.